Update connections in Excel 2010 via VBA, one connection at a time
Good morning!
I have a spreadsheet, created on 365 but some users who would need to use it have Excel 2010
I have some connections that need to be updated separately, I cannot use Refreshall.
On the 365, I use:
    SpreadsheetOrigem.ListObjects("OCs").Refresh
    SpreadsheetOrigem.ListObjects("Stock").Refresh
    SpreadsheetOrigem.ListObjects("Demands").Refresh

But in Excel 2010, this code doesn't work.
I tried:
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("OCs").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Stock").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Demands").Refresh

And the strange thing is that the first connection updates normally, but the other connections don't update.
It seems that the update is "pending" and does not accept others.
Even with the background turned off.
I appreciate any help.
Help in VBA to work in various versions.
